# Puntero que es pasado a una funcion void

Tags: c, funciones, punteros

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    
    typedef struct {
        int age;
        char name[50];
    } Person;    
   void FAMILY_createMembers(int num_members, int *operation_status, Person **family_members) {
    *family_members = (Person *) malloc (sizeof(Person) * num_members);
    if (family_members == NULL){
        *operation_status = 0;
    }
    else{
        *operation_status = 1;
    }
}

    Family FAMILY_requestFamilyInformationAndCreate(int *operation_status) {
    int i;
    int num_members;
    Person *family_members;
    Family family;

    printf("Family members? ");
    scanf("%d", &num_members);

    FAMILY_createMembers(num_members, operation_status, &family_members);

    if (*operation_status == 1) {
        family.num_members = num_members;
        family.family_members = family_members;

        for (i = 0; i < family.num_members; i++) {
            printf("Name? ");
            scanf("%s", family_members[i].name);
    
            printf("Age? ");
            scanf("%d", &family_members[i].age);
        }
    }

    return family;
}
```

Aunque en linea y en la clase me encuentre que asi es como se pasa el malloc cuando un puntero es pasado a una funcion:

```
*family_members = (Person *) malloc (sizeof(Person) * num_members);
```

El programa que utiliza mi universidad me lleva a un error de "Segmentation fault (core dumped)".
Sé que este es el problema porque cuando intento editar la linea solo me aparece problemas en esa linea y y en nada más.

```
family_members = (Person *) malloc (sizeof(Person) * num_members);
```

**tester**.c: In function ‘FAMILY_createMembers’:

**tester**.c:56:17: error: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]

family_members = (Person *) malloc (sizeof(Person) * num_members);

Que es lo que estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: ¿Dónde está declarada la variable `family_members`? La usas en la llamada a la función `FAMILY_createMembers` pero no veo la declaración de esta variable por ningún lado

Comment: Un error, es members solo, no family_members

Comment: Usa algún depurador como `gdb`.. eso te dará la linea exacta de donde ocurre el segment fault.

Answer (score 0):

Esta línea

```
 family_members = (Person *) malloc (sizeof(Person) * num_members);
```

Debería ser realmente así

```
 *family_members = (Person *) malloc (sizeof(Person) * num_members);
```

Por otro lado, la comprobación siguiente también está mal

```
if(family_members == NULL){
```

Te falta un asterisco

```
if(*family_members == NULL){
```

Comment: Otro error que hice aca pero no en el codigo original, gracias por decir, lo de if(*members == NULL) ya lo intente, sigue siendo un segmentation fault y creo que igual esta mal porque con if (members == NULL) me aparece correcto. Edicion: Las dos forman no muestan error.

Comment: @Diego edita la pregunta y pega el código tal cual lo tienes, si no es complicado darte una respuesta adecuada

Comment: ok, lo hice como esta en el codigo la funcion Family FAMILY_requestFamilyInformationAndCreate está ya dada por el ejercicio y no se puede editar.

Comment: @Diego revisa la respuesta

Comment: En la pregunta dice que caundo escribo *family_members = (Person *) malloc (sizeof(Person) * num_members); me da un "Segmentation fault (core dumped)"

Comment: @Diego es bastante probable que ese error no se produzca en esa línea sino en otra parte de tu código. Los errores de segmentación se dan cuando accedes a memoria que no te pertenece. Una asignación de malloc no puede provocar error de segmentación

Comment: Entiendo pero, el error de segmentation fault se quita cuando edito la linea  *family_members = (Person *) malloc (sizeof(Person) * num_members); a family_members = (Person *) malloc (sizeof(Person) * num_members);, donde el unico error que aparece es el que esta dicho en la pregunta

Comment: También digo que el main y el Family FAMILY_requestFamilyInformationAndCreate es dada por el problema, o sea no puedo editarlo y debería estar bien

Comment: @Diego https://onlinegdb.com/HJxWnEZ0Eu <-- aquí tienes la prueba de que lo que yo te estoy diciendo no provoca un error de segmentación

Comment: He utilizado ese programa y a veces no sale problemas que si salen en otros compiladores. Por desgracia me toca utilizar el que usa mi universidad.

Comment: @Diego lo mismo el compilador de tu equipo no funciona correctamente, o no estás compilando correctamente. Seguramente el profesor debiera darte algo de soporte al respecto